# Two-factor authentication

Tags: перевод, it

Is there a term in Russian corresponding to English *two-factor authentication*?  If I want to search for Russian-language results for "two-factor authentication" what should I put into the search engine (Google or Yandex)?

Comment: Да, _[двухфакторная аутентификация](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)._ Удивлены?

Answer (score 5):

Two-factor authentication == Двухфакторная аутентификация.

Answer (score -3):

I would translate "two-factor authentication" as "двухшаговая проверка подлинности".

Comment: _Двухшаговая проверка подлинности_ — это _two-step verification_, что, строго говоря, не вполне то же самое, что _two-factor authentication_. Всякая двухфакторная — двухшаговая, но не наоброт. Например, пароль + секретный вопрос — это несомненно двухшаговая, но никоим образом не двухфакторная.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Странно что удалили ваш ответ, но если к нему добавить этот комментарий уже никто не придерется что ответ слишком короток.

Comment: @Artemix Да я не сегодня заметил, что кто-то из наших модераторов стал брать на себя слишком много: не первый раз уже, когда что-то здесь внезапно пропадает в обход голосования. Но в данном-то случае ответ для публики не удалили, а «разжаловали» в комментарии — так что ничего не потерялось. А если вы хотите взять, что я тут понаписал, за основу и запостить в виде ответа — так это бога ради. Тогда можно еще будет упомянуть разницу между «аутентификацией» и «верификацией», которую я проигнорировал.